# Extracting an image from a running Flash SWF file?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, flash

Is there a way to extract an raw image file from a SWF file that is already running in a browser?

I have had limited success by installing FlashFirebug (Firefox 14.0.1) and then doing the following:

1. use "Inspector" to select the Bitmap a tree hierarchy of objects
2. click on all extraneous objects and drag'n'drop them out of view
3. take a screen shot

Does anyone know a proper way to export the *original* image file?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/46800/possible-to-extract-compiled-flash-file

Answer (score 1):

First, save the swf file (you can find the url in your network tab).  There are a few flash decompilers, for example http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/

You can download a free trial

Comment: FYI: free trial only lets you extract a couple of images and not as a normal bitmap format and no video content. I was not able to use it to extract images to use on webpages maybe the pay version has more export options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WEB-Design/Flash/SWF-Picture-Extractor.shtml ?

Also, read this post [How to extract images from swf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448188/extracting-image-from-swf-file)