# Ways to extract font / svg file from an old flash based website?

Tags: svg, flash, fonts, dump

I'm trying to see if it's possible to extract font & svg data from an [archived flash website](https://web.archive.org/web/20180106002046/http://www.bionic-systems.com/archive/portfolio2001/)

Is this possible?

Note: I am using this [extension](https://modernkit.one/flash-emulator/) on my chrome to run flash website

[Screenshot of flash website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byEy1.png)

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448188/how-to-extract-images-from-a-swf-file)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

1. Download the .sfw that contains font or vector file. If the fonts are not embedded in SWF, it will not work.
2. Open the .swf with [Action Script Viewer](https://www.buraks.com/asv/) to extract .ttf